# Getting no results found in web app application insights & logs

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

As you can see in image in my web app application insight users and in web app logs also i am getting 0 users, no results found .
As you can see it is the image of my web app applicating insights image so application insights is enabled and also i choose time range also.
Can you please help me how can i get this works and get details.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hocFD.png)

I have taken below sample react app from microsoft document in my azure devops repo.
https://github.com/staticwebdev/react-basic
This is my sample react app in DevOps and created web app by taking Node 18LTS as runtime stack. Browsing sample react app working fine but i want user information in web app logs & application insights.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJ3ql.png)
As shown in above image application insights is enabled but still in logs& application insights user i am getting 0 results found after changing time range also.

please let me know am i missing anything & how to get those user results instead of 0 results.

Comment: Please paste the code where you are logging to application insight

Comment: @Ajay Managaon sorry I am not sure about what you are asking. I just taken sample react app code as mentioned in my post and created web app.when I am creating it automatically created application insights and in web app features I can see application insights is enabled.

Comment: @AjayManagaon please let me know if I am missing anything. I am new to azure & devops so As you mentioned in comment how can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [**Azure Application Insights JS SDK or NPM Package**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk?tabs=npmpackage) and some custom code to enable User and session insights for your React app.

Refer my Source code in this [**Github repository**](https://github.com/sid24desai/react-basic).

Install the package below:-

```js
npm i --save @microsoft/applicationinsights-web
```

In your **src directory** create one **appInsights.js** and add the code below:-

```js
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web';

const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
  config: {
    connectionString: 'InstrumentationKey=xxxxx2182;IngestionEndpoint=https://australiacentral-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiacentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/',
    /* ...Other Configuration Options... */
  }
});

appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackPageView();

export default appInsights;
```

Import this appInsights in your App.js and update your **App.js** with the code below:-

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import appInsights from './appInsights'; // Import the configured appInsights

function App() {
  const value = 'World';

  useEffect(() => {
    // Track a page view when the component mounts
    appInsights.trackPageView();

    // Example of tracking a custom event
    appInsights.trackEvent({ name: 'App Loaded' });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      Hello {value}
      {/* Your app content */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

***As your sample React repository is based on Static Web app, I recommend using Azure Static Web app:-***

**With Azure Static Web App:-**

Now, I have created one Azure Static Web app with Source as  Other , Then Configured its Deployment Token in a Azure Static Web app Preview Task:-

**My Complete YAML Pipeline:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    app_location: '/'
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'xxxxxxxx65a-969f-xxxxxx3317853'
```

[image]

[image]

**Pipeline Ran Successfully and My Azure Web app got deployed:-**

[image]

[image]

***In Application Insights, The User was visible:-***

[image]

[image]

If you want to connect Application Insights with your Azure Static web app, You need to connect your function app with your static web app and then enable the Application Insights. But above custom code method will work without connecting Application Insights too.

**With Azure Web App:-**

For Azure Web App Node as runtime and OS: Linux connected to Application Insights:-

[image]

My Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

variables:

  
  azureSubscription: 'xxxxxx0b069'

 
  webAppName: 'valleysilicon'

  
  environmentName: 'valleysilicon'


  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: valleysilicon'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              WebAppName: $(webAppName)
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
              StartupCommand: 'npm run start'
              ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
              InlineScript: |
                npm install
                npm run build --if-present
```

**Output:-**

Deployment successful:-

[image]

[image]

Users visible in Application Insights connected to Azure Web app:-

[image]

[image]